# git remote -v vs. grunt buildcontrol:heroku

Tags: git, heroku, repository

I'm using Angular Fullstack.  When I use `git remote -v` command, it tells me one Heroku repository but when I actually push the code to Heroku it goes to another repository.  Why is this and how do I line it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Angluar Fullstack app, take a look at the DOMAIN configuration variable using the following [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) command:

```
heroku config:get DOMAIN
```

If this matches where you are actually deploying to, then you can also change the deployment location using the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) command

```
heroku config:set DOMAIN=yourherokuapp.herokuapp.com
```

Substitute `yourherokuappname` for the name of your actual heroku app.

For general node.js apps, Heroku recommends its own node.js buildpack which has support or Grunt built in.

If the above does not work, I suggest creating a new Heroku app using the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) command `heroku create` and following the instructions in this tutorial to deploy your app

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-with-grunt

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!